# Flask application to run though Jenkins pipeline from Azure VM

Tags: python, azure, flask, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am facing the same issue as this [user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/845400/i-am-able-to-run-my-python-flask-app-on-azure-vm-b.html). Unfortunately, the solution provided did not work for me even after I set up a new Azure VM for Jenkins, connected the GitHub repository containing the Flask application with Jenkins and set up Azure inbound port rules as instructed. The Flask application runs on the local machine from http://127.0.0.1:5000. However, I cannot see it running after the Jenkins pipeline build, which just keeps running after displaying about debugger on Jenkins Console Output:

> - Debugger is active!
> - Debugger PIN: 494-545-230

Eventually, the site cannot be reached as it takes too long to respond (ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT).

This is the very basic pipeline scripted to run hello.py:

```
pipeline{
  agent any
  stages{
    stage('setup'){
      steps{
        sh "sudo apt install python3-venv -y"
        sh "python3 -m venv venv"
        sh ". venv/bin/activate"
        sh "pip3 install -r requirements.txt"
      }
    }
    stage('run python app'){
      steps{
        sh "python3 hello.py"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Any recommendations about further/alternative troubleshooting methods would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked the firewall rules in the VM?

Comment: Yes, is there anything particular I should change there?